# What REALLY happens when I free() before malloc?(I know something will go wrong but WHAT?)

Tags: c

I am asking the above stated weird question to only improve my understanding about dynamic memory allocation.

In addition to above question I run the following code snippet on codepad.org.

```
void main()
{
   static int a = 10;
   int* b = &a;
   free(b);
}
```

I am  getting "Segmentation fault" message on output window.What is this?May be I am accessing restricted memory through free()?

Also If a don't Initialize 'a' then Nothing is displayed on output window.
Please help me out understanding this behavior.

Comment: what is your objective? What would you expect to happen?

Comment: It is called "undefined behavior".

Comment: Why down vote?I Searched a lot trying various combinations,the linked question didn't pop up.Is the asked question is wrong?Why discourage peoples by down voting?Is it my fault that I cant come up with word combinations that previous question has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get undefined behavior, since you're passing a pointer to `free()` that was not acquired by `malloc()` (or one of its sibling heap allocations functions, like `realloc()` & co).

Of course `free()` can't know this, and avoid treating the pointer as if it were valid. Thus, it will assume it can find whatever book-keeping data it needs associated with the pointer, in whatever way was chosen by your particular memory allocator implementors.

Note that there is nothing "magic" about `free()`, it's just a function. In particular, it doesn't have access to any more information than that which is passed in, i.e. a single pointer.